# Why does my wifi keep turning off and on?

Tags: wi-fi, att

I'm using an LG G5 with an AT&T mobile plan.

My wifi keeps turning off and back on every 30 to 60 seconds. If I enable wifi in the settings, it just disables itself 30 to 60 seconds later... and then 30 to 60 seconds after that, it turns itself back on... and it just cycles like this.

I've googled this problem and can tell that several people have had this problem, but none of the relevant solutions seem to work.